# My Model is not getting updated

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7, django-models

I am a newbie to Django-web _framework.
I created the models.py and defined the class i need as table. My Database is **PostgreSQl**

When i run

> python manage.py syncdb

for the first time it created the default tables.
The class i defined was not created.
When i re-run the same code :

Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

My new table is not created.
Any guesses what is the problem.

Comment: Is your module listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: no i did not add it.   is this the correct way of adding it ?? 'django.outcome.models'

Comment: i added outcome.models in INSTALLED_APPS, and re-ran the query, still not working

Comment: You need to run through the introduction to Django as this is very basic. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: `django.outcome.models` is not the correct way of adding your module to `INSTALLED_APPS`. Instead, just add `outcome` if that is what your directory name is. Remember that you'll also need to have an `__ini__.py` in that directory.

Comment: I did all those.. i have a __init__.py and also added the app string to my installed apps. when i run "python manage.py sql app_name" i get the correct query, but my syncdb dosent update anything

Comment: it worked , i forgot to refresh the database..

Comment: Cool. Glad you got it working. Remember also that syncdb will not execute `ALTER_TABLE` statements. You'll need to use South for that.

Comment: thanks for south :) :) will go through it. now able to create models put data into database through admin site of django, now have to start with login and putting form data into database. if you have any specific referal other than official docs please do let me know. will help me @TimmyO'Mahony Brandon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common problem of forgetting to add it to the installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ....
   'your_project.you_app',
)
```

Your project name should be obvious (Name of the folder that houses manage.py).
Your app name is the folder that has your new models.py.

make sure your installed apps have commas between the strings